# How to properly move array item when `UICollectionViewCell` position is changed

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView`, on which user can change position of the cells, after looking at every Swift Drag and Drop page. I settled on a method to be able to update the array of strings the keep track of the collection view in this function:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {

    let positionPreviouslyHoldingTheSelectedIndex = list[sourceIndexPath.item] 

    // put the select index in the intended destination index

    list[sourceIndexPath.item] = list[destinationIndexPath.item]


    // put the cell/index of the destination index in the selected positions old index

    list[destinationIndexPath.item] = positionPreviouslyHoldingTheSelectedIndex
}
```

But above code update the array as expected and it gets weird, how I would update the array/list once the `moveItemAt` is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 `IndexPath`s, you have to get rid of the array element from `sourceIndexPath` and add it to `destinationIndexPath`, as such:

```
    let item = list.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.item)
    list.insert(item, at: destinationIndexPath.item)
```